# jQuery Ajax passing response variable to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Javascript function that uses jQuery Ajax to fetch response from a Servlet. It works when I use the **anonymous function** method-

```
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'Authentication',
        data : { userName : 'poko' },
        success : function(data){
            alert(data);                               //this works
        }
    });
}
```

But when I try to pass the response variable to a **declared function** nothing happens.

```
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'Authentication',
        data : { userName : 'poko' },
        success : showResult(data)                     //this doesn't
    });
}

function showResult(d) {
    alert(d);
}
```

Firefox debug gives a **ReferenceError: data is not defined**.
Can I actually get the second method to work?

Comment: What if you specify the 'declared function' in the ajax parameters as simply `showResult` ?  Leave out the parens and the parameter.

Comment: If i do not pass any parameters the code actually reaches `showResult` and executes whatever is in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second attempt

```
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'Authentication',
        data : { userName : 'poko' },
        success : showResult(data)                     //this doesn't
    });
}
```

you are actually executing `showResult` and then assigning its result to the `success` handler. What `success` expects is an anonymous function or a function reference(without passing parameters to it).

What you can do is

```
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'Authentication',
        data : { userName : 'poko' },
        success : showResult                  
    });
}
```

and the `data` will automatically be passed in as the **first** parameter to the function referenced.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you dont need the anonymous function, just do `success : showResult`

Comment: Where does `data` in `showResult(data);` come from.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of that parameter you pass in, that invokes the function immediately! If you're passing the function, params will be autopassed in:

```
success : showResult
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are passing the result of showResult to success instead of passing the function showResult.

Do it like this:

```
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'Authentication',
        data : { userName : 'poko' },
        success : showResult                    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By `showResult(data)` you are actually *calling* the function. *success* expects a *function* and not a *function call*.

So it should actually look like

```
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'Authentication',
        data : { userName : 'poko' },
        success : showResult     //Should work now.
    });
}
```